# How to extract tags name and description in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I want to use the name and description present in tags_metadata inside the method. I don't how to do that is there any way I can use those attributes

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

tags_metadata = [
    {
        "name": "select name",
        "description": "Operations with users. The **login** logic is also here.",
    },
    {
        "name": "items",
        "description": "Manage items. So _fancy_ they have their own docs.",
        "externalDocs": {
            "description": "Items external docs",
            "url": "https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/",
        },
    },
]

app = FastAPI(openapi_tags=tags_metadata)


@app.get("/users/", tags=["users"])
async def get_users():
    return [{"name": "Harry"}, {"name": "Ron"}]


@app.get("/items/", tags=["items"])
async def get_items():
    return [{"name": "wand"}, {"name": "flying broom"}]
```

here I want to select the first name attribute from tags_metadata in the get_users() method

output need to be -- > "select name"

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/metadata/?h=+tags#use-your-tags

Comment: In what situation you might need this?

Comment: Is there any code you could share? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI 

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/dummy", tags=["dummy2"])
async def dummy():
    ... 

@app.post("/dummy2", tags=["dummy2"])
async def dummy2():
    ...
```

Let's assume we have these routes. By checking each route from `app.router`, we can find the paths.

```py
@app.get("/tags", tags=["tags"])
async def tags():
    tags = {}
    for route in app.router.__dict__["routes"]:
        if hasattr(route, "tags"):
            tags[route.__dict__["path"]] = route.__dict__["tags"]

    return tags
```

When we hit the `/tags` endpoint we will see this.

```json
{
   "/dummy":[
      "dummy2"
   ],
   "/dummy2":[
      "dummy2"
   ],
   "/tags":[
      "tags"
   ]
}
```

Comment: in case of using  APIRouter? I need the extract particular endpoint tags name

Comment: use APIRouter's instance's name. `app` is just an instance.